# create pdf of a div CSS

Tags: css, pdf-generation

How can I save a pdf of a div, for example :

```
<button>pdf</button>

<div>some data</div>
```

onclick of button I want to save this div as a pdf document.

Edit : is it possible using only CSS?

Comment: have you a plugin installed?

Comment: With CSS? Nope. Most likely you'd either need a browser plugin or generate the PDF server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You need PHP export HTML to PDF:

http://pdfcrowd.com/i/php-export-html-to-pdf.html check this link.

Alternatively you can use this: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6638-PHP-Generate-a-PDF-file-with-a-listing-of-data-records.html

I hope this will help you!
PS: you haden't offered us more info, code you tried etc.